# When searching a specific page on my website it is displaying it in Japanese language

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-index

I am searching my website's page indexing of About us (mentioned below) on browsers but it is giving me details on other languages which we haven't added anywhere.

Consulting with the front-end team they have only added code in English language and the SEO team has deleted this URL from Google Search Console and re-indexed it. It was fixed for 1 week but the problem arose again.

```
site:https://www.magnusonhotels.com/about-magnuson/
```

Attaching screen grab for reference

[image]

If website has a malware in it, then how to find one and remove it as I am newbie to this.

Any help is appreciable.

Comment: Your site has been hacked.  You need to remove the malware from it.